# Need info on Oracle database server

Tags: database, oracle

I am not sure If I'm correct in posting in this forum but I need info. I am doing University project which needs couple of oracle database server which are online. I have a cloud application which would access this servers. I tried to find online if I could rent database servers for a week for the test with no luck. Could somebody provide any info on where I could rent oracle database servers.

Thanks,
Shashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it would be difficult to find plain Oracle database hosting.  It's an "Enterprise" thing, which means companies never bother to explain their services on their website.  But you can find relatively cheap Oracle APEX hosting.  (APEX is a rapid application development for Oracle.)  It's probably much cheaper to rent that and use the Oracle functionality that comes with it.

Or you can always install your own system, although Oracle installation can be painful.  If this is just for testing, you can download any version.  You might want to start with 10g Express Edition:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to commission an Oracle instance on Amazon's Elastic Cloud (EC2). I've done this myself. If you start with an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that already has Oracle installed, that's most of the work done for you already. Here's more info to get you started:

http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/global-solution-providers/oracle/

Answer (score 0):

If the Amazon EC solution is unacceptable, the easiest way to go is probably to start with a Linux+Oracle VM, and look for a provider who does VM hosting, or self-host if you have access to a machine somewhere with a permanent internet connection / address.