# Install Oracle 11g Database (or 10g) on an old laptop

Tags: database, oracle, memory-management, oracle11g

I'm trying to use an old laptop (Win2000 P3 1.1Ghz 256MB ram) as an oracle database server for a small group project of 3/6 people on my college.
I don't need much, just some databases with 2 accounts, 10/15 tables, some views and triggers, however even the simplest database requires 1GB of physical ram (2GB of swap) and the installer refuses to overlook this need.

Is there a simple Oracle server database that I can install on this system without upgrading it?

I would really like to reuse this 9yo laptop as a server since it isn't really doing much besides gathering dust at a corner, but all the software seems to have high requirements for something so simple as a MySQL database.

Comment: This is SuperUser or ServerFault question... That said, there are a number of linux distros that are designed for servers, so I assume you could use one of these.

Comment: The lack of RAM, followed by being a laptop means this doesn't have horsepower worth dedicating to a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11g won't install on something this small. Given that a Standard Edition license is a couple of thousand dollars, why try to run it on hardware that is worth a tenth of that cost.

You may be able to use the [Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html) (which has the added advantage of being free to use). The requirements suggest it can [barely](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#BABDHJHB) run on 256 Mb. Personally, I'd spring for a memory upgrade. Stick a note up in the college, as there's probably someone who has done a RAM upgrade on a laptop and has some old chips lying around.

I'd also dump Windows and go for a simple Linux install.

Comment: I've tried to install the express edition but even that one gives the not-enought-memory error (since the svga card and the cpu share memory the real physical memory is just ~222MB), as for the memory upgrade the motherboard caps it at 512MB so no luck installing the 11g, I will give a try on the express edition on a vm before buying a memory upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can install any current version of Oracle on such a system.  Have you considered using Amazon or some other hosting solution?  See [Need info on Oracle database server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592532/409172)